# Android studio - Team Services Oauth sign in

Tags: android, tfs

I try to set up source code control in Android studio 3.1 to work with Microsoft Team Services. I installed Visual Studio Team Services plugin, and installed TF utility. Now when i try to import project into version control first i have to sign in. I use menu `VCS/Import` into version `control/Import` into team services GIT. I click on Sign In link to sign in into MS team services account:

[image]

But i only get Oauth2.0 Authorization request blank page and i cannot sign in.

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Hello, the question is: does someone experienced the same problem. How do i sign in to Team services if Oauth authorisation request don't render user interface for signing in ?

Comment: I managed to make it work. It seems the problem was mixing 32Bit Android studio and 64bit JDK and JRE. I first uninstalled JDK's and JRE's (all the different versions i have installed on my computer) and installed only las 64bit versions for Windows 10. After that i started studio64.exe (64 bit version of Android studio) and Oauth worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. It seems the problem was mixing 32Bit Android studio and 64bit JDK and JRE. I first uninstalled JDK's and JRE's (all the different versions i have installed on my computer) and installed only las 64bit versions for Windows 10. After that i started studio64.exe (64 bit version of Android studio) and Oauth worked.

Answer (score 0):

First please make sure you have installed the plugin successfully.

The Team Services plugin for Android Studio is available in the [Android Studio Plugin Repository](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services). The plugin can be installed from Android Studio by browsing the Plugin Repository. Suggest you install from there and select the latest version.

Check your network related setting, disable anti-virus temporarily and turn off the proxy. Check if you could connect to VSTS successfully directly through web. You could also test with some other app with OAuth2.0, such as POSTMAN if it could access your resources correctly once logged with OAuth2.0.

This kind of issue mostly related with your environment, also check your environment configuration.